# Zapier action with support for multiple files

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I have a Zapier Action that currently has support for a single file attachment. I am looking to make the Action support multiple files which are mapped to the same field.

Using the Trello Zapier app as an example, I can see multiple files are supported by separating the different file inputs with a comma. Example:

[image]

When using the `file` field type the file gets converted into a pointer for later use in the Zap, which I am currently handling.

Ideally I was looking for a solution where I could do what is similar in the Trello app.

I was hoping the following would work and then I could loop over the files and append them to my `FormData`.

```
bundle.inputData.files.split(",")
```

However this only seems to return the first file that has been mapped to the field.

```
[
  'https://zapier.com/engine/hydrate/:censored:7:3253ac4a5c:/.eJxVzksOgyAQgOG7zFpaUHweohdoGoMwGCKCEUxjjHcvfWy6_WfyzRwgvYvoYh_3BaGDG2RgXIjCSeyNgo7RlrK2rooM5Bain7eA63fCGsoZzUBI6bdE_EVt0KreifmtamMxJHl6inUM0B2f0i_epONrCvcDJtzTZiiuPC-LQmlJhrweCC9zQRrULVGat0wj6krpZP1olZ4X1u7E-tFfFjfC-TjPFyM9RQ4:1lEuaX:GDjfyeC0mtdhdw47AVimeUHfdG4/'
]
```

Any anyone got a solution that overcomes this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to this working by setting `list: true` on the field in `inputFields`.

I can then loop over the file pointers in the `perform` function on my action, where I get the file data and filename and append them to a `FormData` object. I used this [example](https://github.com/codebycaleb/zapier-hydration-example/blob/master/creates/uploadFile.js) as a guidance for getting the file data and filename.

```
{
    key: 'files',
    type: 'file',
    label: 'Attachment',
    list: true
}
```